# images in laravel 10 don't display when production

Tags: laravel-10

I have written the following code in laravel.

```
if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
            $file = $request->file('foto');
            $nama = 'foto-' . date('YmdHis') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('public')->put('img/' . $nama, file_get_contents($file));
            $user->foto = "storage/img/$nama";
        }
```

this code works in local but when going up to production the file cannot be displayed . the filesystem config

```
<?php

return [

   

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

   
    'disks' => [

        

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

I tried this code

```
Route::get('/symbolic_link', function(){
    $targetFolder = storage_path('app/public');
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);
});
```

but it's still an error

Comment: Checked httpd logs?

Comment: Try using `.`prior to `/` in the paths to the images. For example, instead of `'img/'` use `'./img/'`